# How can I get HttpHeaders.TryGetValues() to return several values?

Tags: c#, http, system.net

I’m using [HttpHeaders.TryGetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.trygetvalues) but I can’t figure out how to make it return **several** values.

Here is what I’m trying:

```
using System.Net.Http;

var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://httpbin.org/response-headers?X-Numbers=0,1,1,2,3,5,8");
var success = response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Numbers", out var values);
Console.WriteLine($"{success} ({values.Count()}) -> '{values.First()}'");
```

And here is the result:

`True (1) -> '0,1,1,2,3,5,8'`

As usual, the documentation is really sparse and all it says about the `values` parameter is

> The specified header values.

[RFC 2616 section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2) describes how an HTTP header can have several values (emphasis mine):

> **Multiple message-header fields** with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a **comma-separated list** [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same field-name are received is therefore significant to the interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

As we can see, the values are comma-separated so I’d expect an enumerable with 7 vaules (`0`, `1`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `5` and `8`) but instead `TryGetValues` returns a single string value.

Is there something I can do to make it return several values?

Comment: I don't know, but you might consider `values.SelectMany(v => v.Split(",").Select(s => s.Trim()))` just to catch both return types and be done with it.

Comment: Yes I could, but what’s the point of returning an Enumerable<string> if it always return a single value and I have to do the work myself?

Comment: That's the thing. I don't know if it *always* does, or if it depends on how the headers were added, etc. The MSDN documentation is certainly lacking, as you pointed out.

Comment: Well that’s my question: Is there something I can do to make it return several values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that TryGetValues returns an enumerable is that you can provide multiple headers with the same name, also each header can have multiple values separated with commas, as you mentioned. i.e `"https://httpbin.org/response-headers?X-Numbers=0,1,1,2,3,5,8&X-Numbers=6"`.

I agree it would be better to have each comma separated value as a single value in the returned values enumerable but current implementation assumes that each header can only return one value.

Comment: Ha, *multiple headers with the same name*, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/CacheControlHeaderParser.cs), it appears the parser for the Cache-Control header is kinda unique:

> The Cache-Control header is special: It is a header supporting a list of values, but we represent the list
>   as *one* instance of `CacheControlHeaderValue`. I.e we set `SupportsMultipleValues` to `true` since it is
>   OK to have multiple Cache-Control headers in a request/response message. However, after parsing all
>   Cache-Control headers, only one instance of `CacheControlHeaderValue` is created (if all headers contain valid
>   values, otherwise we may have multiple strings containing the invalid values).

Asking for Cache-Control will always return a single `String`, and as far as I can tell, there's no way (short of a PR against [donet/corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)) to trick it into dividing it up for you. However, *other* headers will have different behavior.

As to why the Cache-Control header is treated specially in this way, you'd have to ask the actual developers. That file hasn't changed significantly since the open source release.

For other known headers, there is a big list: [KnownHeaders.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/KnownHeaders.cs). From there you should be able to dig into any specific header you're interested in.

Comment: I edited the question to take Cache-Control completely out of the equation by using a custom `X-Numbers` header instead.